# Date()コンストラクターの引数に配列を使用するには？

Tags: javascript

関数f2の結果をf1と同じにしたい場合、f2にステートメントを追加することで、この問題を解決できますか？そのような解決が可能である場合、解決策の例は何ですか？

```
let date;f1();f2();

function f1(){date = new Date(1970,0,1,0,0,0,0);console.log(date);}
// Thu Jan 01 1970 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (日本標準時)

function f2(){
 const array = [1970,0,1,0,0,0,0];
 date = new Date(array);
 console.log(date);
}
// Invalid Date
```

Comment: [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

たとえば、[スプレッド構文](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) を適用することで問題を解決できます（コメントによる提案）。

```
date = new Date(...array);
```